# Ansible - skip the Play Recap

Tags: ansible

I'm making a small video clip of some Ansible output.
For convenience purposes, I'd like Ansible to skip the Play Recap 'task', is this possible?

I've searched online, but without succes.

Comment: You can play as much as you like with the output of Ansible with [callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html). So that's maybe a pointer to "google" it, something like _"callback plugin no recap Ansible"_.

Comment: Also, you can scan a bit in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/callback/

Answer (score 0):

##### 1. Run `ansible-doc -t callback -lv` to see list of available plugins.

> I think the one you want is **community.general.selective**
>
> This callback only prints tasks that have been tagged with `print_action` or that have failed. This allows operators to focus on the tasks that provide value only. Tasks that are not printed are placed with a '.'. If you increase verbosity all tasks are printed.

##### 2. Define this option in `ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = community.general.selective
```

---

What it looks like when `stdout_callback = community.general.selective`

```sh
$ ansible-playbook examples/test1.yml                
..

# STATS *******************************************************************************************************************
localhost    : ok=2 changed=2   failed=0    unreachable=0   rescued=0   ignored=0
```

What it looks like when `stdout_callback = default`

```sh
$ ansible-playbook examples/test1.yml

PLAY [blocks-example] ************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Task 1] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Task 2] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Right, that’s an improvement. However, I was looking for a solution that does not display “STATS ##..” and “localhost =...” as well. Just do not display any information about the play